# Giving error "d is undefined" in Firefox and "handler not defined" in IE in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery 1.4.2, below code was working before with JQuery 1.3, can you please suggest what is issue with the below code as if I comment this code then there is no error coming on page.

```
$(".load-control").each(function()         
        { 
            var $objThis = $(this);
            var fname = $objThis.attr("href");          
            ($objThis).bind("click",false); //Removing the attached click event 

        });
```

Please suggest!!

Comment: Shouldn't you use unbind() to remove events from an object?

Comment: why `($objThis).` and not `$objThis`. Since it's already a jquery object.

Comment: @JohnP: *"Since it's already a jquery object"* It doesn't matter what it is, the parens serve no purpose regardless.

Comment: @T.J Crowder, you're right, just noticed that there is no `$` preceding the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove handlers:

```
$(".load-control").each(function()         
{ 
    var $objThis = $(this);
    var fname = $objThis.attr("href");          
    $objThis.unbind("click"); //Removing the attached click event handler
});
```

The above will remove *all* `click` handlers from the element. If you just want to remove the specific one you set earlier, you can do that, e.g.:

```
// Earlier, when setting up
$(".load-control").each(function()
{
    $(this).click(handleLoadControlClick);
});

// The unhooking code you quoted
$(".load-control").each(function()         
{ 
    var $objThis = $(this);
    var fname = $objThis.attr("href");          
    $objThis.unbind("click", handleLoadControlClick); // Remove that specific handler
});

// The handler
function handleLoadControlClick(event) {
    // ...
}
```

More in the docs linked above.

(Off-topic: The parens around `$objThis` in your `bind` call served no purpose, so I removed them.)

Answer (score 0):

try `($objThis).bind("click",function(){return false;});` or undind function

Comment: Your `($objThis).bind("click",function(){return false;});` solution does something *very* different from what he says he wants. It attaches an *additional* handler that cancels the event, whereas he said he wants to remove the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try unbind function `$($objThis).unbind("click")`